# Photoshop: How do you make the corners of a square straight?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, corners

I know this question might sound confusing. I just didn't know how to say, so I provided a video of what i'm trying to do.

I know you need to use the path selection tool to change the corners but no matter how hard I try to it always comes out round.

I am trying to do what the person [in this video](https://gyazo.com/62b121bf010174716e7c47ff2551417c) does to their shape.

Comment: Please next time try not to write everything in one giant sentence, it's difficult to read. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create beveled corners, as in that video -- simply draw a rounded rectangle, then switch to the **Convert Point Tool** and click the corner anchors.

[image]

By clicking the anchors you convert them from smooth (rounded) to corner (squared) points. Thus removing the curve.